# Why is my React version 16 page not rendering?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn React mostly for work but the reason is immaterial.  The tutorial on React's website didn't show correctly (styles all screwy) so I decided to try to create my own "Hello World" app.  But it's not even showing on the screen.  It's just a white screen unfortunately.  Here's the code - It's not 100% as simple as it can get but the only thing simpler would be maybe 2 lines less so I'm leaving it:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

class Person extends React.Component
{
    constructor(params)
    {
        super(params);

        this.state.name = null;
    }
    
    render()
    {
        if(this.state.name == null)
            return(<div>Hi, What's your name? <input type="text" onBlur={() => this.setState({name: this.val()})} /></div>);
        else
            return(<div>Hello, {this.state.name}!</div>);
    }
}

class App extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return(
            <div id="app">
                <Person />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

Comment: Does it compile? What errors appear in the console?

Comment: Do consider switching to functional components. That's been the trend, and along with hooks it can be a simpler approach.

Comment: The ctor state initialization needs to actually set `state`, e.g., `this.state = { name: null }` Your console should be warning you. The next issue will also be logged in the console.

Comment: (The blur event.)

Comment: It claims to compile successfully, no errors or warnings whatsoever - I had some warnings and remedied them and I've had errors too when I forgot to do something in the past but what's wrong with the blur?  I'll fix the constructor's state issue though.  But not sure what's wrong with the blur.

Comment: @SethD.Fulmer Events take an `event` parameter. That's where you get the value from. But the console log shows both the state error and will then show the event handler error.

Comment: Thank you!  While eents do take an event parameter, that is optional a colleague pointed out and then he suggested a refactor of: event.currentTarget.value which seems to work except now I'm trying to find an event that I can use when the user presses Enter from the field.  If you put something as an answer I'll accept and upvote it.  Thank you again!!